# Android - Can PushLink do silent updates?

Tags: java, android, updates, silent-installer

Does anyone know if [PushLink](https://push-link.com/) can do silent updates? That is, download the app and install it without any interaction from the user?

The PushLink website is quite sparse on documentation regarding features available so I can't be sure.

Or does anyone know if it's possible to have a silent installer for android? I basically have android devices that will not do any user interaction and I need to be able to update my apps running on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no official way to install anything on Android device without user interaction. Which is a good thing, because it prevents a lot of possible malware and exploits from working.

Comment: That's not strictly true: the Play market app has options for auto-update.

Comment: The Market uses undocumented/hidden methods of PackageManager, which are not currently available to the app developers. There are some tricks to get access to those methods, but it does not work reliably across different Android version. Anyway, would you allow third-party app with INSTALL/DELETE_PACKAGES permissions on your phone? I would not.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible since version 3.1.0 released at 2012.04.23.

Take a look at NINJA strategy

> NINJA (Only for rooted devices) The application is just re-launched in
>   a new version. There isn't notification. BETA!